# JavaScript Template Replace Statements

Tags: javascript, regex, templates, replace

I am building a JS template by hand, and though the HTML is coming out correctly, the URL, imageurl, and title aren't being replaced within the forEach loop. I'm not certain what I'm doing wrong in my replace statements.

Here's the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
        jQuery.getJSON("http://APICALL", function(data) { 
        var popular = data;

        if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(popular)) {
            // null
            } else {

            var outerTemplate = '<div class="col-xs-12 header">\
                                    Header Stuff\
                                </div>';

            var innerTemplate = '<a href="{url}" />\
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 article">\
                                        <div class="blog-img-wrapper" style="background-image:url({imageurl});"></div>\
                                        <h3>{title}</h3>\
                                    </div>\
                                </a>';

            popular.data.forEach(function(contentData) {
                var compiledHtml = innerTemplate.slice(0);

                console.log(contentData.title);

                compiledHtml.replace(/{url}/g, contentData.url);
                compiledHtml.replace(/{imageurl}/g, contentData.image_url);
                compiledHtml.replace(/{title}/g, contentData.title);

                outerTemplate = outerTemplate.concat(compiledHtml);
            });

            jQuery('#popular-posts').html(outerTemplate);
        }

    });
```

And here's what it looks like on the page:
[image]

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot and forgot that replace returns a new string. So my issue was that I never set the variable compiledHtml to the replace statement.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery.getJSON("http://APICALL", function(data) { 
    var popular = data;

    if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(popular)) {
        // null
        } else {

        var outerTemplate = '<div class="col-xs-12 header">\
                                Header Stuff\
                            </div>';

        var innerTemplate = '<a href="{url}" />\
                                <div class="col-sm-4 article">\
                                    <div class="blog-img-wrapper" style="background-image:url({imageurl});"></div>\
                                    <h3>{title}</h3>\
                                </div>\
                            </a>';

        popular.data.forEach(function(contentData) {
            var compiledHtml = innerTemplate.slice(0);

            compiledHtml = compiledHtml.replace(/{url}/g, contentData.url);
            compiledHtml = compiledHtml.replace(/{imageurl}/g, contentData.image_url);
            compiledHtml = compiledHtml.replace(/{title}/g, contentData.title);

            outerTemplate = outerTemplate.concat(compiledHtml);
        });

        jQuery('#popular-posts').html(outerTemplate);
    }

});
```